# Docker tomcat not accessible from browser

Tags: tomcat, docker

I have started a container with some ports open and tries to access the web interface of Tomcat from browser but it's not working.

```
1)docker run -ti --rm --name server -p 3456:5678 tomcat:8.0 // not working with localhost:3456
2)docker run -ti --rm --name server -expose 8080 tomcat:8.0 //not working localhost:8080
3)docker inspect server // to see the ip:port and tried to access using it as well but no luck
```

I am using CentOS7 with docker instaled.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very simple:

1. is not working because you are binding to container port 5678 which is not used by tomcat (see `EXPOSE` commands in [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/60aabb354b1b0c9724631d82890ba7e308104d76/8.0/jre7/Dockerfile))
2. is not working because you did not bind to a host port (`-p` is missing)

This works:

```
docker run -ti --rm --name server -p 9090:8080 tomcat:8.0
```

Open `localhost:9090` in your browser.

Comment: Can you please solve my question?  I am using my organization's Tomcat setting.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813959/docker-container-exited-immediately-on-windows-machine/70814204#70814204