# Tomcat hosted on centos:centos7 docker container, can't view webpage outside of container

Tags: tomcat, docker, ports

I setup a docker container which has a nat'd ip of 172.17.0.2 (from my centos virtualbox image, via nat).

If I ssh into the container's ip (I know, bad practice) and open firefox, I can see the service hosted at 172.17.0.2:8080, but outside the container I cannot (although I can ping it).

I initially thought it was a firewall rule, but the image doesn't even support firewall access (although the hosting vm does).

I did a docker run  --expose=8080 to the container, and it still results in me being unable to view the webservices that is hosted on the container.

I'd prefer to use the docker's ip for viewing the content rather than trying to forward the port through the host's ip (i.e. my virtualbox image which is a 192.168.3.x address).

I thought this might be a firewall issue on the virtualbox image itself (vs the container).  If so, I'm confused as to how the networking works, as my docker container appears to have an nat'd ip from virtualbox's nat.

Comment: Don't use expose, use `-p 8080:8080`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker tomcat not accessible from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583303/docker-tomcat-not-accessible-from-browser)

Comment: what I may need to do is do a -p 192.168.0.x:8080:8080 or something like that, and then on the host machine, have duplicate network adapters.  I don't think docker wants you to use it's nat'd ip.