# Docker container exited immediately on Windows machine

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on Windows machine. I want to run tomcat setup from my Windows machine to Docker container.

My dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9
RUN mkdir -p C:/Users/project/Y
COPY TQ C:/Users/project/Y

WORKDIR C:/Users/project/Y

ENV JAVA_HOME C:/Java8/jdk1.8
#ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

ENV TOMCAT_HOME ./TomcatB/tomcat
ENV TOMCAT_BASE ./TomcatB/tomcatBase
ENV CALD_CONFIG_DIR ./TomcatBuild/config
EXPOSE 8080
RUN sed -i 's/port="0060"/port="8080"/' ./TomcatBuild/config/server.properties
ENTRYPOINT ["./TomcatBuild/tomcat/bin/startTenant.sh"]
```

Image gets created here , but running command : "docker run -d project T"  or docker run -p  8080:8080 -d project T** starts container which Exists immediately**.
Tomcat is running.

Why Container gets EXITED immediately?

```
loadProperties()
{
if [ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]; then
echo "server.properties=${CALD_CONFIG_DIR}/${TENANT_ID}/server.properties"
fi
. ${CALD_CONFIG_DIR}/${TENANT_ID}/server.properties
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: The property loading phase failed. Unable to read ${CALD_CONFIG_DIR}/${TENANT_ID}/server.properties so halting with status=1"
    exit 1
fi
}

validateProperties()
{
if [ "${TomcatListenPort}" = "" ]; then
    echo "Error: TomcatListenPort is not defined in server.properties. T
```

Comment: If the container doesn't show up in `docker ps`, then that means the script `startTenant.sh` has finished running. A Docker container will only run for as long as the entrypoint script is running

Answer (score 1):

The container will exit at the end of the `ENTRYPOINT` script you specified here:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./TomcatBuild/tomcat/bin/startTenant.sh"]
```

What is the contents of the startTenant.sh script?

If your script needs to stay working, the script will need to stay wait until the container is stopped for some reason.

The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) has an example of how to keep Apache Tomcat running. The script can pause while awaiting input:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Note: I've written this using sh so it works in the busybox container too

# USE the trap if you need to also do manual cleanup after the service is stopped,
#     or need to start multiple services in the one container
trap "echo TRAPed signal" HUP INT QUIT TERM

# start service in background here
/usr/sbin/apachectl start

echo "[hit enter key to exit] or run 'docker stop <container>'"
read

# stop service and clean up here
echo "stopping apache"
/usr/sbin/apachectl stop

echo "exited $0"
```

Another way to keep the container running is to make apache run in the foreground:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: @Paul: My EntryPoint is: ENTRYPOINT ["./TomcatBuild/tomcat/bin/startTenant.sh"]  and I also have to pass "AMI1" while running "docker run -p 8080:8080 -d project AMI1".  How to use your ENTRYPOINT  in this case?

Comment: @Paul: I have added startTenant.sh file. Kindly have a look. I have tried everything to keep container running, but it always gets EXITED immediately.  Tomcat is running. But it does not open login screen for our WebApp on neither port 9960 nor 8080. The configuration files in TQ folder have TomcatListenPort: 9960. I want to run it on some other port.

Comment: @Paul: running ENTRYPOINT ["./TomcatBuild/tomcat/bin/startTenant.sh", "AMI1", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]  doesn't do anything to container. It exists immediately.

Comment: Actually , the startTenant.sh is tenant based. So, I have to pass "AMI1".  And in this case , "-D"  and "FOREGROUND" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Look man, we can't tell exactly why is this container crashing from your side, I would recommend to start by looking at the logs that might point you out on why the container failed! command to list all containers, including failed / crashed containers:

```sh
docker ps -a
```

Now you will be able to find the id / name of your failed container and run the following command to check it's logs:

```sh
docker logs [container-id]
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @Allan: I found, Tomcat is running. But why Container gets exited? Why it is not in running state?

Comment: *With his dockerfile, nobody can tell at the moment why*. Exactly. The question does not have the necessary information for it to be answered properly, so you shouldn't reply. Your answer should be a comment.

Comment: @Paolo: I have edited question with script file.

Comment: @Paolo: Hi, now the question have necessary information.